# Store the result in new columns, named based on another variable (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. What I need is to calculate the difference between the variables `A` and `B`, and store the result in the new columns based on the variable `df['Value']`. If the `Value == 1`, then the result is stored in column named `Diff_1`, if the `Value == 2`, then column `Diff_2`, and so on.

Here is the code so far, but obviously the line `df_red['Diff_' + str(value) ] = df_red['A'] - df_red['B']` is not doing what I want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'E:\...\.xlsx')
print(df)

value = list(set(df['Value']))
print(value)

for value in value:
    df_red = df[df['Value'] == value]
    df_red['Diff_' + str(value) ] = df_red['A'] - df_red['B']


Out[126]: 
   ID  Value      A     B
0   1      1   56.0  49.0
1   2      3   56.0  50.0
2   3      4  103.0  44.0
3   4      2   89.0  44.0
4   5      1   84.0  41.0
5   6      1   77.0  43.0
6   7      2   71.0  35.0
7   8      4   77.0  32.0
print(value)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

After a simple operation of `df['A'] - df['B']` the result should look like this.

```
Out[128]: 
   ID  Value      A     B  Diff_1  Diff_2  Diff_3  Diff_4
0   1      1   56.0  49.0     7.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1   2      3   56.0  50.0     0.0     0.0     6.0     0.0
2   3      4  103.0  44.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    60.0
3   4      2   89.0  44.0     0.0    45.0     0.0     0.0
4   5      1   84.0  41.0    43.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5   6      1   77.0  43.0    34.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
6   7      2   71.0  35.0     0.0    36.0     0.0     0.0
7   8      4   77.0  32.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    45.0
```

Not so great way of doing this would be like this, however I am looking for some more efficient, better ways:

```
df['Diff_1'] = df[df['Value']==1]['A'] - df[df['Value']==1]['B']
df['Diff_2'] = df[df['Value']==2]['A'] - df[df['Value']==2]['B']
df['Diff_3'] = df[df['Value']==3]['A'] - df[df['Value']==3]['B']
df['Diff_4'] = df[df['Value']==4]['A'] - df[df['Value']==4]['B']
```

Comment: Looks efficient enough. I d have done the same way ;) Or maybe tried and timed this approach as well: df.loc[df['Value'] == 1, 'Diff_1'] = df['A']-df['B']

Comment: It works well, however, if I had a 100 unique values, then write a 100 lines of df['Diff_1'] = df[df['Value']==1]['A'] - df[df['Value']==1]['B'] would not be good at all.

Comment: I see. You can make a loop then. Let me anwser not in a comment. Give me a minute or two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach which may not be fastest, but it's a start:

```
for i in df['Value'].unique():
   df.loc[df['Value'] == i, 'Diff_' + str(i)] = df['A'] - df['B']
   df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Output of my fake data:

```
  Value A   B   Diff_1  Diff_2  Diff_3  Diff_4
0   1   20  2   18.0    0.0     0.0     0.0
1   1   30  5   25.0    0.0     0.0     0.0
2   2   40  7   0.0     33.0    0.0     0.0
3   2   50  15  0.0     35.0    0.0     0.0
4   3   60  25  0.0     0.0     35.0    0.0
5   3   20  7   0.0     0.0     13.0    0.0
6   4   15  36  0.0     0.0     0.0     -21.0
7   4   14  3   0.0     0.0     0.0     11.0
```

Comment: Comment on what's happening. First find unique values of the column we want to calculate. Then we loop those unique values, and according to them do calculations and create new column based on those unique values. We later end up with NaNs which we later fill in with 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df.join(df.set_index(['ID', 'Value'])
          .eval('A-B')
          .unstack(level=1).add_prefix('Diff_')
          .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
```

output:

```
   ID  Value      A     B  Diff_1  Diff_2  Diff_3  Diff_4
0   1      1   56.0  49.0     7.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2      3   56.0  50.0     NaN     NaN     6.0     NaN
2   3      4  103.0  44.0     NaN     NaN     NaN    59.0
3   4      2   89.0  44.0     NaN    45.0     NaN     NaN
4   5      1   84.0  41.0    43.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   6      1   77.0  43.0    34.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
6   7      2   71.0  35.0     NaN    36.0     NaN     NaN
7   8      4   77.0  32.0     NaN     NaN     NaN    45.0
```